# C float in NASM x86 assembly

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

In my university project i have to use binary representation of float number in x86 assembly for arithmetic operations. Using FPU is forbidden so i try to read float number and return it as DWORD but whatever i try to do i get "-nan". Any advices?

Edit:
I use gcc and it's 32 bit code

Declaration in C (i can't change that)

```
extern "C" float func(float num);
```

*.asm file

```
section .text
global  func

func:
;prolog
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp

; zapamiętanie rejestrów zachowywanych
    push ebx
    push esi
    push edi

    mov eax, DWORD [ebp+8]
    ;mov eax, 0xffffffff i checked that but i still get the same result

; odtworzenie rejestrów, które były zapamiętane
    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx

;epilog 
    pop ebp
    ret
```

Example result (for 256)

```
01000011100000000000000000000000
11111111110000000000000000000000
num1: 256.000000
num2: -nan
```

Edit:

C code without checking bits part

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern "C" float func(float num);

int main()
{
    float num1;
    float num2;

    scanf("%f", &num1);
    num2=func(num1);

    printf("num1: %f\nnum2: %f\n", num1, num2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which C compiler are you using? The `.asm` extension hints at some Microsoft variant, but I cannot be sure. This is important because there are a variety of calling conventions; I don't know which one your system is using.

Comment: GCC on 64bit linux ubuntu

Comment: The convention says to place floating point arguments and the return value in SSE registers. In your case that means `num` is in `xmm0` and that's where it should be returned too.

Comment: ... but the .asm code is clearly 32-bit...

Comment: My bad. I should have told you my program have to be 32 bit one (i use 64bit linux but here it doesn't matter)

Comment: Your *Declaration in C* is actually a C++ declaration ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare the return type func as `float` the result will be returned in the FPU (ST0). For returning a value in `EAX` you have to declare it as an integer type. For `printf` you have to fake a float. Example:

**caller.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
extern float asmfunc1(float);
extern uint32_t asmfunc2(float);

int main (void)
{
    printf ("asmfunc1: %f\n", asmfunc1(456.78));

    uint32_t ifl = asmfunc2(123.45);
    float* pfl = (float*) &ifl;             // Faking a float
    printf ("asmfunc2: %f\n", *pfl);

    return 0;
}
```

**callee.asm:**

```
section .text
global asmfunc1, asmfunc2

asmfunc1:
    fld dword [esp+4]
    ret

asmfunc2:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    leave
    ret
```

**Build & run:**

```
nasm -felf callee.asm
gcc -m32 callee.o caller.c
./a.out
```

Answer (score 2):

In the 32 bit Linux ABI, `float` values are actually returned as `long double` at the top of the 8087 FP stack. You cannot return a `float` without using the FPU.

What you are probably restricted from doing is FP operations for addition, subtraction... But you still need to load the result in the FP stack to return it.  In 64 bits mode, you would return `float` values as `double` in the `xmm0` register.

Try changing the code to this:

```
    section .text
    global  func
func:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    flds    8(%ebp)
    pop     ebp
    ret
```